# Copy Paste between Different Workbook

Tags: vba, excel, copy-paste

Hi I want to copy and paste the range to mainworkbook, however, the range is pasted at babyworkook8 instead. Please help

```
Option Explicit
Dim mainworkbook As Workbook
Dim babyworkbook8 As Workbook


Sub Copypaste()
Set babyworkbook8 = Workbooks.Open("\\C:\IT Charges\IT Charges August.xlsx")

babyworkbook8.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D4:F27").Copy
Set mainworkbook = Workbooks.Open("\\C:\Users\ivan\Desktop\IT Charges\IT 
Summary Charges.xlsm")


mainworkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("R1").PasteSpecial


End Sub
```

Comment: Suggestion: put your sets one after the other, in this way you paste directly after the copy.  Use Worksheets(".....") instead of Sheets("......")  I take it you are working in a 3rd workbook that is neither of the ones in the code.  Close the workbooks in your code as well when you are done, or the open might flag already open with an error.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit long winded, but it clearly defines the source and destination ranges:

```
Sub CopyPaste()
    Dim SourceBook As Workbook
    Dim DestBook As Workbook
    Dim SourceSheet As Worksheet
    Dim DestSheet As Worksheet
    Dim SourceRange As Range
    Dim DestRange As Range

    Set SourceBook = Workbooks.Open("\\C:\IT Charges\IT Charges August.xlsx")
    Set DestBook = Workbooks.Open("\\C:\Users\ivan\Desktop\IT Charges\IT Summary Charges.xlsm")
    Set SourceSheet = SourceBook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set DestSheet = DestBook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set SourceRange = SourceSheet.Range("D4:F27")
    Set DestRange = DestSheet.Range("R1")

    SourceRange.Copy DestRange

End Sub
```